# Spread jobs on many cores [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab, multicore

Is there a MATLAB command (or command through the terminal), where I can specifically tell MATLAB on what of my eight cores to process my code? Note, that I do not mean that I want to do parfor's (parallelize a for loop), I want to run many scripts which are essentially the same, but with different input parameters, on different cores.

The solution that comes off the top of my head is to just open 8 different terminals, execute MATLAB, and run each script, but I feel like this is inefficient since the 8 scripts may be running on the same core. Or does MATLAB intelligently separate the scripts into the 8 available cores?

I'm hoping there's some sort of command of the form:

```
 $ matlab script1.m -setcore 1
```

or a MATLAB line of code that I can add, at the beginning of each script to force the process on a certain core. For example: Script1.m:

```
%Script1.m
clc;close all;clear all;
set_core(1);

%Script 1 lines begins:
```

- I have an intel Xeon and an Nvidia Titan X (although the graphics part is irrelevant, since I do not want to do parallel computation at the graphics level, or for convolutions).

Comment: Did you try just to run your job several times? Every `Matlab` process should run on different core. @Daniel : Sorry, there's some mess in my head about bitness and multicore processors. Removed those comments.

Comment: @Arturo: Did you run a single instance to verify it is really single-core code? A single instance might already using your full cpu capacity making all the attempts useless.

Comment: @Daniel how would I check if one core is being used at full capacity? Essentially would I be running the htop command?

Comment: @Arturo: Assuming you are on linux, es top is a possible choice. [Note that 100% indicates full usage of a single core](http://superuser.com/questions/457624/why-is-the-top-command-showing-a-cpu-usage-of-799)

Comment: @Daniel It's at around, 188.7%. Only on one processor I assume? However, when I run htop, all the cores are at about 25% on average, 50% is the max of one. So I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: That means parts of your code use multi-core operations. With that numbers I recommend not to assign dedicated cores because it will kill any speed you could gain using multi-cores. Try it with 4 to 5 parallel instances of matlab, more will probably decrease the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the discussion in the comments, I guess you will have the best performance starting 4 to 5 instances and let the scheduler do everything. The more processes you run in parallel the more likely they produce cache misses or you run out of memory, so typically the smallest number of working processes using the full CPU capacity is the best choice. In some cases you might have to chose an even lower number because memory or other resources are the bottleneck.

Matlab has no option to assign it to a dedicated core, most operation systems don't let programs do this decision. [You can do it using taskset](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23106/limit-process-to-one-cpu-core). In matlab you only have the coice to limit it to one computation thread using the [-singleCompThread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html) option.